# Why does typeof null misbehave in switch statements?

Tags: javascript, null, switch-statement, typeof

It is commonly known that

```
typeof null
```

returns "object".

However, I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
switch(typeof null){
    case "object": 
        1; 
    default: 
        3;
}
```

This code returns 3.

Why does "object" as returned by typeof null not cause the first branch of the case statement to be executed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing `break` for the first case - so it falls through to the `default` case and returns 3.

```
switch(typeof null){
    case "object": 
        1; 
        break;
    default: 
        3;
}
```

Comment: A classic blunder!

Thank you